# How to get subclipse source code and build it?

Tags: eclipse, svn, plugins, subclipse

I want to download the svn plugin--subclipse  source code, and then build it by myself, then intergrate subclipse to the eclipse 4.5.

Can you tell me how or where to get the subclipse source code and how to build it please?

Please help me. Thank you very much.

---

I have get the source code from this link below:

http://subclipse.tigris.org/source/browse/subclipse/

I have build the subclipse by ant, Now I will try to use Eclipse to build it.

Thank you very much for everyone's reply.

Comment: Have you tried googling it? Searching "subclipse source code" has http://subclipse.tigris.org/source/browse/subclipse/ as the first result

Comment: yes. I have get the subclipse  source code successfully.But I tried to buid it with ant before. Now I will try to use the eclipse.  I am not a java programmer, do not know such ant, maven and some other tools, I will try my best to learn it.Thanks for your repley.

Answer (score 1):

There is a wiki page with some information.

[Subclipse Development](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/SubclipseDevelopment)

I do not maintain it much, but the process has never really changed so I would assume it is up to date.  I build Subclipse by building the Update Site project via the Eclipse UI.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have get the source code. I tried to build subclipse source code by using ant before. I have build the Eclipse 4.6 and CDT.  Now I will try to use Eclipse to build it.

Answer (score 0):

The source code is here: http://subclipse.tigris.org/source/browse/subclipse/

To build it, try importing the projects into Eclipse. Once you have a specific problem, please ask an additional question on SO.

Comment: Thank you. I have check out the source before.  Now I will try to import into eclipse.  I thought that I can build it by ant, but I failed.